# Установка Elasticsearch на убунту 14.04

Tags: elasticsearch

Устанавливаю еластиксерч и при попытке запустить сервер и перейти на хост : `http//:localhost:9200` получаю ошибку: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused`

Сначала не мог понять в чем ошибка, но оказалось, что еластик не показывает еррор меседжы если сервер не стартует, а все равно пишет "ОК". Нашел в логах следующие ошибки, выкладываю полный стектрейс:

> root@elk-server:/etc/elasticsearch# log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/elk-server.ss.lu.log (Permission denied)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:133)
>       at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
>       at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
>       at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
>       at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
>       at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
>       at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:128)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupLogging(Bootstrap.java:204)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:258)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
>   log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [file].
>   log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/elk-server.ss.lu_deprecation.log (Permission denied)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:133)
>       at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
>       at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
>       at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
>       at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
>       at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
>       at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:128)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupLogging(Bootstrap.java:204)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:258)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
>   log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [deprecation_log_file].
>   log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/elk-server.ss.lu_index_indexing_slowlog.log (Permission denied)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:133)
>       at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
>       at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
>       at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
>       at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
>       at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
>       at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:128)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupLogging(Bootstrap.java:204)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:258)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
>   log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [index_indexing_slow_log_file].
>   log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/elk-server.ss.lu_index_search_slowlog.log (Permission denied)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:133)
>       at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
>       at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
>       at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
>       at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
>       at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
>       at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
>       at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:128)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupLogging(Bootstrap.java:204)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:258)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
>   log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [index_search_slow_log_file].

У меня файлы по тем путям где должны хранится логи и тд и тп они просто не создаются так как нету прав (Access denied). Как быть в этой ситуации? Возможно у еластика есть какая-то дефолтная папка в которой создаются эти логи при установке? Кто может подсказать?

Comment: Под каким пользователем запускаете эластик, есть ли у него права на запись в `/var/log`? Кстати, есть хорошая роль https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-elasticsearch.

Comment: под рутом запускаю

Comment: для начала надо посмотреть путь " /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/" и что там с правами, если его нет то создать и дать права, посмотреть что будет писать ES. и что если зайти браузером на - http://localhost:9200/